# How to query a table in an entity in Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

This is for a REST API, so this is related to making the JSON POSTs easier to use. I have two entities, Customer and Role. To keep it simple:

```
Customer: Long id, String name, List<Role>
Role: Long id, String name -- this is a static system table I populate i.e. "User", "Admin"
```

Internally, I do the whole many-to-many relationship, but I don't want to expose the role.ids in the json, so I do the wrapper thing with map where I end up with:

"roles": [ "User", "Admin" ]

So far so good. The GETs work exactly how I want them to.

Now I'm trying to implement the POST. In this case, I need to take the "roles" array and convert it back to internal List.

I can do that with:

```
    this.roles = roles.stream().map(role -> { return new Role(0L, role); })
                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

That also works fine. Except the roleId's are all 0 obviously. My idea was to create a RoleRepository and AutoWire it inside the Customer entity so I could query the Role table by Name to get the id. But this causes an exception to get thrown as it isn't able to create the RoleRepository object within the Customer which is in a CustomerRepository.

Trying to figure out how to populate the roleIds here. As a side question:

I have CustomerController. This just forwards the create request to CustomerService. If I auto wire the RoleRepository in CustomerService it works fine, but I don't think it is the services' responsibility to populate the Ids is it? It seems like Customer should populate them when setRoles() gets called, no? Otherwise the Customer object is going to hold an invalid state until it gets saved whereas if I do it in the customer, it will always be in a valid state.

Comment: If I were to choose, the Id should be autogenerated by the database. Use `identity` or even better - a sequence.

Comment: @Andronicus Customer is the top level entity. A customer contains a list of Roles. Consider Role as a table driven enum. The user cannot create roles. This is for a CreateCustomer() method. The user will pass in [ "User", "Admin" ] and internally I convert it to a Role object so Hibernate can persist the Customer object as well as the Many-To-Many table. It can't save the entities if all the role's have Id=0 and a name since that would violate the FK constraint. Does that make sense?

Comment: yes, but I still cannot understand, why not omit setting any ids and annotate relationship with for example `@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)`. Hibernate and database manage that for you.

Comment: You can annotate the "id" property in Role class with Id & GeneratedValue annotations and when creating the instance or Role, just pass the role name for ex:- new Role("ADMIN"). While persisting hibernate will populate the id for it.

Comment: No, Customer object shouldn't do anything with data. Since it's an entity it has to stay as simple as it possible. Consider it as a dump data container. All logical operations has to be performed by services. If you going to reus this logic in many places, just move it to dedicated service. It could be RoleService or SecurityService. Then autowire this service everywhere you need it.

Comment: @Andronicus As I mentioned, a user cannot create roles. That is a system table. If a user passes in "Admin" and I do PERSIST, Hibernate will create a new "Admin" rather then re-use the existing one in the table. It'll also permit a user to pass in whatever they want.

Comment: @KenBekov Yeah... I'm kind of seeing that thought process when trying googling in related questions, that logic should be in the service. I guess I'm worrying about nothing because the customer id is also 0L until it gets saved and the id generated by the database.

Comment: @KenBekov On the other hand, say the Roles table contains only "Admin" and "User" and somebody passes in "Bob", then the object is in an invalid state until the service rejects it. It kind of seems odd to me that the entity doesn't enforce a valid state by itself, no?

Comment: Entity shouldn't to be responsible for its valid state. It's just a structured data container with no logic inside. When somebody passes "Bob" it doesn't mean they passes an object. They passes just the name of role i.e. string. And service has to check if role having this name is existing. If it is then service creates the role. Otherwise it returns nothing or raises an exception (up to you).

Comment: @KenBekov Ok, thanks, the DI works in the service.